# Responsive links in header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello i want my social media icons in my header to be responsive but when i minimized the browser the social media icons are not showing. Can someone give me ideas how to do it? should i use media queries for this?

Here is the picture when not minimized.
[image]

here is the picture when minimized the social media icons disappeared.
[image]

here is my html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Student Portal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href ="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="style.css" rel ="stylesheet">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="img/png" href="img/asd.png"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class ="top-bar-dark">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-4 hidden-xs">
                        <div class="top-bar-socials">
                            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Governor-Andres-Pascual-CollegeNavotas-City/344134628983014?fref=ts">
                                <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a href="https://twitter.com/official_gapc">
                                <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/governor-andres-pascual-college-in-navotas-city">
                                <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
             <div class="col-sm-8 text-right">
                        <ul class="list-inline top-dark-right">                      
                            <li class="hidden-sm hidden-xs"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> gapc_school@yahoo.com.ph</li>
                            <li class="hidden-sm hidden-xs"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> (02) 282-9036</li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="login"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Login</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my css

```
.top-bar-dark {
  background-color: #a92419;
}

.top-bar-light {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
.top-bar-light .top-dark-right li {
  border-color: #ddd;
}

.top-bar-light .top-dark-right li a:hover {
  color: #32c5d2;
}
.top-bar-socials {
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-top: 5px;

}
.top-bar-socials:after {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}
.top-bar-socials a {
  margin: 0px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size:18px;
  color: #fff;
}

.top-dark-right {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.top-dark-right li {
  line-height: 40px;
  border-left: 1px solid #932015;
  padding: 0px 10px;

}

.top-dark-right li, .top-dark-right li a {
  color: #d7d7d7;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.top-dark-right li i {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.top-dark-right li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
a.login{
  text-decoration: none;
}
.fa-facebook:hover{
  color:#3b5998;
}
.fa-twitter:hover{
  color:#1dcaff;
}
.fa-linkedin:hover{
  color:#007bb5;
}
```

UPDATE:
After i remove the "hidden-xs" they are not align.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that they disappear is because you have applied the "hidden-xs" class to the div containing the social media icons. Remove that class to persist the social media icons. Happy to post code example if need be, but try that as a start. You may want to add styles to media queries to adjust size and position, etc.

Remove class from here:

```
<div class ="top-bar-dark">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-4 hidden-xs">
```

Comment: how can i adjust it to allign to the email?

Comment: How do you want to align to the email? Are you referring to the desktop view? Do you want the social icons aligned right?

Comment: im referring to the email, contact, and login i want the social media icons to align with them. because when i removed the "hidden-xs' they are not align the social media icons is in top of the email, contact, and the login. can you give me clues.

Comment: That makes it a bit more complicated. However, given that the emails are hidden at XS and social icons remain, I think the issue does not exist. If you remove hidden-xs on the emails as well, then there will be too much information within the header at mobile dimensions to make the header useful. Just my $0.02. I have been working in a fiddle to disprove the theory, but it seems to stand.

Comment: No they both remains. the problem is the social media icons is not align to the email. see the picture above. i updated my question.

Comment: It's a matter of applying the correct styles to the parent divs. Besides setting hidden or visible, you should set the col-xs-* class for the containers.  https://jsfiddle.net/chrismauck/4qukjk7p/2/ Updated link

Comment: Thankyouu very much bro! Cheers :D

Answer (score 1):

The `hidden-xs` class on in the 4th div down is causing itself to be hidden when the screen goes below a certain width.

You can remove it and it will keep showing the icons:

https://jsfiddle.net/zj8jc7uf/

Comment: how can i adjust it to allign to the email?

Comment: @nethken, do you mean the 'Login' text?

Comment: @nethken, the email doesn't show up on the mobile view, do you want it to?

To align them in the desktop view you could add this css that will move the right side text down:

`.text-right {
  padding-top: 4px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

The reason that media social icons disappeared is because you applied "hidden-xs" to div container the social media icons.
You can check this at here that I edited

```css
.top-bar-dark {
  background-color: #a92419;
}

.top-bar-light {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
.top-bar-light .top-dark-right li {
  border-color: #ddd;
}

.top-bar-light .top-dark-right li a:hover {
  color: #32c5d2;
}
.top-bar-socials {
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-top: 5px;

}
.top-bar-socials:after {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}
.top-bar-socials a {
  margin: 0px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size:18px;
  color: #fff;
}

.top-dark-right {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.top-dark-right li {
  line-height: 40px;
  border-left: 1px solid #932015;
  padding: 0px 10px;

}

.top-dark-right li, .top-dark-right li a {
  color: #d7d7d7;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.top-dark-right li i {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.top-dark-right li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
a.login{
  text-decoration: none;
}
.fa-facebook:hover{
  color:#3b5998;
}
.fa-twitter:hover{
  color:#1dcaff;
}
.fa-linkedin:hover{
  color:#007bb5;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class ="top-bar-dark">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <div class="top-bar-socials">
                            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Governor-Andres-Pascual-CollegeNavotas-City/344134628983014?fref=ts">
                                <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a href="https://twitter.com/official_gapc">
                                <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/governor-andres-pascual-college-in-navotas-city">
                                <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
             <div class="col-xs-8 text-right">
                        <ul class="list-inline top-dark-right">                      
                            <li class="hidden-sm hidden-xs"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> gapc_school@yahoo.com.ph</li>
                            <li class="hidden-sm hidden-xs"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> (02) 282-9036</li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="login"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Login</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: the problem now is how can i align them? i want to align the social media icons along to email, contact, and login.